# tmux change default working directory of a session without attaching

Tags: tmux, pwd

I'm looking for a way to do something like this *without* attaching to the session.

```
tmux attach-session -c <directory> -t <session>
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Per `tmux(1)`, there isn't a way to change the default working directory (new windows and new panes) of an entire session without attaching to it.

I cannot attach to the session because I'm doing this in some automated scripts where attaching would break the automation.

Comment: potential duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281994/changing-the-current-working-directory-of-a-certain-process

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply

```
tmux attach -c directory -t session 2> /dev/null &
```

the attaching will exit immediately as the forked background job is not a terminal. But it will succeed in changing the working directory of the tmux session.

**Edit:** I corrected `-s` with `-t` but the trick does not seem to work anymore in tmux 3.1b.

Comment: This doesn't work; `tmux attach` returns an error: `unknown option -- s`

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
`tmux send-keys -t <session> 'cd <directory>'`
```

do what you want?

Unsure if this would apply to new windows / panes created after this, but the poor man's workaround would be just to send this to `<session>:<windowID>.<paneID>` after creating that window/pane.